# AOSP build for OTA Package With Error : ValueError: Magic should be 0xED26FF3A but is 0x00000000 Magic should be 0xED26FF3A

Tags: android, android-source

./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files  -i ...

using prebuilt recovery.img from IMAGES...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./build/make/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1532, in 
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "./build/make/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1487, in main
WriteFullOTAPackage(input_zip, output_zip)
File "./build/make/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 486, in WriteFullOTAPackage
system_tgt = GetImage("system", OPTIONS.input_tmp)
File "./build/make/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 316, in GetImage
return sparse_img.SparseImage(path, mappath, clobbered_blocks)
File "/home/android/fresh_android_8/build/make/tools/releasetools/sparse_img.py", line 51, in **init**
raise ValueError("Magic should be 0xED26FF3A but is 0x%08X" % (magic,))
ValueError: Magic should be 0xED26FF3A but is 0x00000000

OTA should generate incremental build.